# Error: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all documents from a collection from Firestore, but when I try to run the code, this error appears:

```
W/DynamiteModule(24949): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(24949): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(24949): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/xample.mypocke(24949): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  (24949): uid=10215(com.example.mypocket) AsyncTask #1 identical 1 line
I/xample.mypocke(24949): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/xample.mypocke(24949): Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

[image: error]

This is the code:

```
class FinancasMensais extends StatefulWidget {
  const FinancasMensais({super.key});

  @override
  State<FinancasMensais> createState() => _FinancasMensaisState();
}

class _FinancasMensaisState extends State<FinancasMensais> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _saidasStream = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('addsaidas').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 172, 178),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Finanças Mensais'),
        toolbarHeight: 90,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)
          ),        
        elevation: 15,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
       stream: _saidasStream,
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Text("ERROR!!He");
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
        );
       },
      ),
     );
  }
}
```

I am programming in VisualStudio and using a physical Moto G7. I don't know what to do and don't know how to get all those documents from the collection.